# SharePoint 2010 restricted document library contributors

Tags: document, permissions, document-library

Is it possible to setup a document library in SharePoint 2010 such that users can contribute, rate, and tag documents, but not edit the document itself once it has been submitted to the document library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to achieve **some** of this using a custom permission pattern.

Copy the Contribute permission pattern and remove permissions like

- Edit Items
- Delete Items
- Delete versions
- Use selv service site creation

Experiment with these permissions to achieve what you want. The point is to keep the user having Add Items permissions. Rating isnt controlled by permissions.

The one thing you probably cannot do without custom event receiver or workflows is tagging up documents, if you by that mean adding meta data to the documents.

Comment: It turns out this was the solution, which I had completely forgotten about.  "Add Items" and "Edit Items" are separate granular permissions... I am not limited to the default permission levels (Contributor, Reader, etc).  I just needed to create a custom permission level that included the "Add Item" permission, but not the "Edit Item" permission.  List of all permissions here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721640.aspx

Answer (score 3):

I dont think you can do that OOTB but it should be possibe by using an event reciever on your document library that listens to ItemCheckingOut event.

Documents need to be checked out before you can edit them and if you listen to the ItemCheckingOut event you can cancel the event and show a message to the user that says the document cannot be edited.

Changing properties (such as tags or rate) is still possible as it doesnt require the user to check out the document.

For more information on event recievers you can check [this quick note](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff728093.aspx) on MSDN and [this awesome post by Tobias Zimmergren](http://www.zimmergren.net/archive/2010/01/05/sp-2010-how-to-event-receivers-and-custom-error-pages.aspx) on how to show custom error pages for your event reciever.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of doing this is setting up Information Rights Management on the library with a such that the document is secured but the library permission levels are set to contribute so the metadata can be captured.  This requires having Rights Management Services active for your domain.