# DocLib permissions - Only edit your own submissions?

Tags: permissions

Related question to [SharePoint 2010 restricted document library contributors](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/11022/sharepoint-2010-restricted-document-library-contributors).  Is it possible to allow contributors to a document library to add documents, edit their own documents, but only read (not edit) documents submitted by others?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lists can set Item-level permissions in the UI using /_layouts/advsetng.aspx

But document libraries dont have this option in the UI

But you could try setting the same properties from powershell/code

SPList.ReadSecurity = 1

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.readsecurity.aspx

SPList.WriteSecurity = 2

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.writesecurity.aspx

Comment: I've set these permissions using powershell, but permissions are still being governed by the settings in the permissions page. Is there a certain permission level I need to set using the GUI before this will work?